# Add permission to taxonomy programmatically

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

I used `hook_user_save()` to create new vocabulary each time user being created/Added.

The question is How to add user Permission for new Vocabulary?

Comment: You are creating a user depending on the title of your node ? It's important to know that permissions are set on role level, so users created need to have a specific role and then you have to add permissions in that role.

Comment: @guilhom yes.. they have a specific role already `'roles' => array(4=>TRUE), ` I delete (same as user)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Drupal comes with a single permission to administer  vocabularies, so if you want your new user to be able to access only the new created vocabulary, you should take a look at the module [Vocabulary Permissions Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr). I never used it, but it sounds to fit your needs.

You'll need to explore how it handles the new permission and configure the module each time you create a new vocabulary.

Comment: so i can't give permissions to user of the same role?

Comment: Users with the same role will have the same permission by default.